# Jquery Mobile listview('refresh') not work

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, refresh

for example please  "jsfiddle.net/wDRLt/14"

please try follow step by step
1.Click on "A001" then It's expand. It's work well for me.

2.Click on "select all" and choose AAA or BBB then It's generate new collapsible set.

3.Click on "A001" again but this time It's not work.

in step 1 listview('refresh') work well but in step 3 it's not work

What wrong in my code?

please help me to solve it's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer by @dragos makes a valid point it isn't the only problem with your code.

I have refactored your code and appended comments.  You can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/9W6Rd/
Important point to note,
Since you are removing and adding elements dynamically.  You will need to delegate the event listener which in essence means that you listen to events on elements that aren't in the DOM on pageload but may be added later. The framework handles the bubbling of the events.
Here the code is working as you hoped.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    html = '<li data-icon="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h3>001</h3><span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini-text">cost 50</span><span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini-text">buy 100</span><span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini-text" >low 120</span><span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini-text">provide 150</span><span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini-text">last 150</span><span class="ui-li-count ui-count-align">(200) 100 bottle</span></a><a href="Item /ItemInfo"></a></li>';

    var TabItem1 = '<div class="colps" id="a001" data-role="collapsible"><h2>A001<span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all custom-count-pos">8</span></h2><ul id="ultab_a001" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="info" data-split-theme="d" class="ui-listview"></ul></div>';

    var TabItem2 = '<div class="colps" id="a002" data-role="collapsible"><h2 >A002<span class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all custom-count-pos">8</span></h2><ul id="ultab_a001" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="info" data-split-theme="d" class="ui-listview"></ul></div>';

    // You need to delegate the expand event as you are re-inserting new .colps elements in the select popup.  This means that you cannot set the listener on the returned elements of .colps from the beginning as they will be replaced in future actions.  See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more info.

    // we are listening to the "expand" event here see http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/
    $(document).on("expand", ".colps", function (event) {
        console.log('clicked');
        // get the ID
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        // get the ul under 'this' which means we are only getting the ul for the selected collapsible
        $('ul', this).html(html).listview().listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    });

    var itemtype = "";

    $('#ulType a').on('click', function (event) {
        // Here we have added type-id's as a data attribute in the HTML see http://api.jquery.com/data/ - it allows us to store arbitrary data associated with an element.
        typeid = $(this).data('type-id');
        console.log(typeid);
        if (itemtype != typeid) {
            itemtype = typeid;
            $("#display-view").html(TabItem1 + TabItem2);
            $("#display-view").collapsibleset("refresh");
            console.log(555);
        }
        $("#popType").popup("close");
    });

});
```

Comment: this is my new code "jsfiddle.net/wDRLt/17" i want to know in 1 step i use $("#ultab_001").listview('refresh') it's work well. But in 3 step i use $("#ultab_001").listview('refresh') again it's not work? it's still loading and collapsible not expand. sorry i'm bad english skill

Comment: This is because the first listview is rendered properly by JQM on page-load.  However you are replacing it with a new listview contained in your `html` variable. Therefore it is a new listview and needs to be instantiated first.  This works for both types `$("#ultab_a001").listview().listview('refresh');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `HeaderClick` function:

```
function HeaderClick(id) {
    id = "a001";  <-- Remove this
    alert(id);
    $("#h2_" + id).unbind("click");
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $("#ultab_" + id).html(html);
    $("#ultab_" + id).listview('refresh');
    $("#div_" + id).trigger('expand');
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
}
```

You made the id variable constant which is not what you want.

I hope i helped you !!

Comment: this is my new code "jsfiddle.net/wDRLt/16" i want to know in 1 step i use $("#ultab_001").listview('refresh') it's work well. But in 3 step i use $("#ultab_001").listview('refresh') again it's not work? it's still loading and collapsible not expand.